# SelectedItem tag doesn't support Custom Names?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a 2 tick repeater clock hooked up to a command block with this command in it...

```
testfor @p {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:tripwire_hook,display:{Name:"Key to a House"}}}
```

When I hold the key, the comparator doesn't go on, and the door doesn't open.

Comment: [Don't use redstone clocks for command block contraptions!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/235449/1351)

Comment: MBraedley, this is only 1 command block for easier door opening on my server. I do use fill / setblock clocks when making contraptions though, so don't worry.

Comment: Even still, don't drop into bad habits.  A setblock clock will also be less laggy than whatever clock you have set up, even if the difference is quite minor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SelectedItem uses the Item Structure, and under Item Structure there is no display tag. The display tag lies under the `tag` tag.

```
testfor @p {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:tripwire_hook,tag:{display:{Name:"Key to a House"}}}}
```

Also note it is suggested to use @a selector instead of @p. Using @p will only activate if the player closest is holding the item.

Comment: You should mark @ModDL's answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark underneath the score if this solved your problem.