# How do I do a /setblock for under a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a vanilla spleef arena, with a redstone clock attached to a `/setblock` command. No matter how I tried, I could not get the command to set the block under the player air. this was the closest I got: `/setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air` is there some way I can attach the `~ ~-1 ~` to `@p`? If not what is another way to do this?

Comment: **Don't use a redstone clock!**  [Redstone should never be used in command block contraptions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235448/), and especially not as your clock source.  There are a few alternatives the run completely in command blocks, but that belongs in a different question.

Answer (score 8):

What you are looking for is the amazing [`execute`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command#execute) command:

> Executes a command on behalf of one or more other entities, with originating permissions, optionally on condition that a single-block /testforblock-style check passes.

The syntax is:

```
execute <entity> <x> <y> <z> <command …>
```

`<entity>` is a target selector, such as `@a`, `<x> <y> <z>` are coordinates from which to execute the following `<command …>` from. In most cases, setting this to `~ ~ ~` (i.e. the exact location of the entity) is fine. To set the block under every player to air, you can use

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air
```

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute positioned as @a run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air`