# How to test for the number of players in a gamemode in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

It want to test for the number of players in a gamemode.

I tried `/testfor @a[m=0,c=1]` but it only tests for the number of players, not the number of players in a gamemode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count entities with commands/check if there are only one or a certain number of entities or players left?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/365931/how-to-count-entities-with-commands-check-if-there-are-only-one-or-a-certain-num)

Answer (score 3):

If a selector such as `@a[m=0]` selects `Alice, Bob, Carol, Dave`, then `@a[m=0,c=2]` will select `Alice, Bob`. `c=2` does not mean *"only select anyone if there are exactly 2 players"*, but rather *"limit the players selected to at most 2"*. Even if there are more than 2 players, the command will still select 2 players and succeed.

When a `/testfor` command is run, a command block's `SuccessCount` tag will be set equal to the number of entities that the selector found. You can then use a `/testforblock` command to check whether the first command block's `SuccessCount` is a certain number.

For example:

```
/testfor @a[m=0]
/testforblock X Y Z command_block -1 {SuccessCount:2}
```

Change `X Y Z` in the second command block to the coordinates of the first command block. You may also need to change `command_block` to `chain_command_block` or `repeating_command_block`.

The second command will only succeed if the first command has a `SuccessCount` of `2` (it found exactly 2 players). You can then run a conditional chain block off of that second command to activate whatever you want to happen when there are exactly 2 players:

[image: Setup]

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of things.  First, the `testfor` command is pretty useless by itself.  It isn't worth learning until you learn `scoreboard`s and `execute`.  A lot of command block contraptions are dependent on those two commands.  Put `testfor` back on the shelf and learn other commands first.  The only thing I find `testfor` useful for is testing that I'm using the correct selectors.

Which brings me to the second thing.  You will only ever detect a single player in survivor mode.  That's what the `c=1` means.  Remove that selector, and you should be good.  Granted, there isn't much you can do with that command in a command block without also using something like `stats` (which pretty much necessitates using the `scoreboard`), since the only other option is to use analog redstone, which besides being effectively dead, is also severely limited.

Comment: So how would you advise I she make something that lets off a redstone signal when there is only 1 person in a radius left in survivel mode while the rest of the players are in spectator mode.

Comment: I would question why you're using redstone at all.  You should try your best [too remove all redstone from your command blocks](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/235448/1351).  To answer your question though, it's a bit complicated.  You might be able to do it with 3 or 4 command blocks, but I'd have to prototype it out first.

Answer (score 0):

To check for how many findings your `testfor` found, you can use a second command block with a `testforblock` command. It's syntax, as described on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#testforblock) is following (`[]` are optional entries):

```
testforblock <x> <y> <z> <block> [dataValue|state] [dataTag]
```

So to test *if* there is a command block at the coordinates `X`, `Y`, `Z`, the command is

```
testforblock X Y Z minecraft:command_block 0
```

where the `minecraft:` and `0` are optional.

Additionally, command blocks containing a `testfor` obtain a value called `SuccessCount`, which is the number of found entities. You can't extract this value though; you can only test if the command block has a certain SuccessCount:

```
testforblock X Y Z minecraft:command_block 0 {SuccessCount:S}
```

to check if the command block at `X`, `Y`, `Z` has a SuccessCount of *exactly* `S`.

The `c=1` parameter in your command will trigger only to the first player in survival gamemode, so be sure to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

## 1.13 Update

The `m` argument has been changed to `gamemode`, and the full name must be provided: [`survival`,`creative`,`adventure`,`spectator`]

The replacement for the `/testfor` command is `/execute if entity`:

```
execute if entity @e[gamemode=adventure]
```

You can get the count of entities by placing the `store` subcommand before the `if` subcommand:

```
execute store result score FakePlayer myObjective if entity @e[gamemode=survival]
```

You can test for the number by using `/execute if score`:

```
execute if score FakePlayer myObjective matches 0 run ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I have another way using scoreboard first command block: `/testfor @a[m=0,c=1]` then a chain command block above it: `/scoreboard players add @p Gms 1`

then put this command in chat: `/scoreboard objectives add Gms dummy`

Comment: All that does is set a player's score and nothing else. A score simply existing doesn't do anything. That particular setup won't do anything anyways to answer the question.

Comment: but he said the number of the players in a gamemode he can see from that score How many players are in gms

Comment: What your setup is doing is constantly adding 1 to the nearest-players score so long as there is a player in survival mode. It doesn't set a score based on the number of players in survival mode. It'll count up nonstop and does not represent the number of players in survival.