# How to set a dummy scoreboard objective to another dummy

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a couple of command blocks that are capable of emitting a redstone signal whenever the player jumps. I thought I would do it by constantly checking whether the Jump objective was the same as a dummy objective which always changes itself to the Jump objective.

To get to the point I need to set a dummy scoreboard objective called OldTotalJumps to an scoreboard objective which I've named TotalJumps. I have tried: `scoreboard players set OldTotalJumps TotalJumps` but it keeps coming up with the error: "TotalJumps is not a valid number".
I hope someone can help.

Comment: As a side note, [please don't mix redstone and command blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/235448), its a really bad idea.  Instead, if you need to activate some redstone based on a command block, use the `setblock` command to place a block of redstone in an appropriate place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a better way of solving your problem. Instead of creating a new dummy objective, you can simply reset the `jumps` objective to 0 every tick.

You would need to run the following command once:

```
/scoreboard objectives add jumps stat.jump
```

And these on a clock:

```
/execute @a[score_jumps_min=1] ~ ~ ~ do stuff
/scoreboard players set @a[score_jumps_min=1] jumps 0
```

Of course you replace `do stuff` with the command/function you actually want to run.

If you're still interested in solving the exact problem you posed, there is a different `/scoreboard` 'subcommand' that can do that: `operation`. The following command sets the command executor's `oldtotaljumps` score to its `totaljumps` score.

```
/scoreboard players operation @s oldtotaljumps = @s totaljumps
```