# Minecraft World Loaded Detection Using Redstone (Save file load detection)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I've been trying to search for an answer to this question for some time now
(World Load Detection / Chunk Load Detection / Join World / etc)

However, despite my effort, I've been unable to find a solution...

### Details:

- This is a single-player world, NOT a private or public server
- The use of command blocks is acceptable
- It needs to activate when I open the world, but only once

  - (and every time the save is loaded, but only once)
- It is a 1.15 save file

I found a lead on this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/technicalminecraft/comments/7vr2gz/worldchunk_loaded_detector/

This also seemed promising but I couldn't quite follow...
https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/2828667-custom-join-message

However, the solution appears to be outdated (1+ year ago) and no longer works in version 1.15

Does anyone have any ideas?

I've tried the /tag and /scoreboard approach but those only seem to work on servers (local or public) since the command blocks will be running regardless of players being on the server
With this being a local save (and not a server), that does not appear to work.

Comment: What exactly is that question?

Comment: Using redstone, is it possible to detect the load of a world... (with or without the use of command blocks)

Comment: Why are you adding the restriction of requiring the use of redstone?  It might be the case that redstone is required, but that isn't reason enough to artificially restrict possible solutions.

Comment: What would be the alternative?

Comment: The alternative is to just not use redstone, and for commands, [you shouldn't be using redstone anyway](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/235448/1351).

Comment: Commands are acceptable, but whatever the solution it should not be a manual solution (running a command every login).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With commands it's easy:

```
/scoreboard objectives add leave custom:leaveGame
```

This ticks up once for every time you leave the world, so it can be detected on the next server tick (when you have joined again). I do not know how it behaves when Minecraft is killed or crashes.

Example usage:

```
/execute if entity @a[scores={leave=1..}] run say The world was reopened.
/scoreboard players reset * leave
```

Comment: "/scoreboard objectives add leave leaveGame" >> "unknown criteria 'leaveGame' "

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot "`custom:`". Some special scoreboard types have that, some don't, seemingly randomly.

Comment: /scoreboard objectives add leave minecraft.custom:minecraft.leave_game "DISPLAYNAME"
(For 1.15)

Thanks for the update! I'm trying to implement this into my world now, I'll update my post with setup and accept after I get it working.

Comment: `minecraft:` is optional, as well as the display name, which is only displayed in the sidebar if you make your scoreboard visible there.

Comment: No, don't put the answer into your question, it's called "question" for a reason.

Comment: My example usage was already complete, no need to add anything to it. You don't need to set the display name manually to the exact same that the scoreboard ID already is, because it would appear like that anyway. You don't need to have a display of that scoreboard, because it shows as 0 for everybody at all times anyway. You don't need to add 0 to everybody's score, because 0 and no score work the same in this case. I don't know what the other three command blocks on your right side do. You also don't need to put the `/scoreboard objectives add` command into command blocks, you can just …

Comment: … execute it from chat. You also don't need to add 0 in the loop, that does nothing for you. And I really recommend not to use redstone in command block contraptions if you can at all avoid it (you almost always can), see reasons here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/235448/171580

Answer (score 2):

I showed this question to some experts about the limits of what redstone can do, but they didn't respond. :(
So I found a solution myself: My initial idea was that chunk loading detectors might work as world loading detectors as well. It turns out that this is true, even when you close and re-open the world inside the chunk with the detector inside it. So you just need to put one of those detectors e.g. every 320 blocks in both X and Z direction for render distance 10 and somehow get the output to where you want it.

Now the problem of building a chunk loading detector. I found a very easy one on Reddit, which works in 1.15.2 as well: https://www.reddit.com/r/technicalminecraft/comments/7vr2gz/worldchunk_loaded_detector/

Here is an image. Everything is self-explanatory, except this: The armour stand wears frost walker boots.

[image]