# Copying & pasting multiple commands to Minecraft terminal

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

**Update: Using this I created this [tool for copy & pasting QR codes into Minecraft](https://craftqr.com/)**

I  wanted to compose a bunch of commands in an external editor and then paste them all to execute in the Minecraft console (chat window).

But if you paste multiple lines, it seems to just ignore the line breaks. My next thought was to use a separator between commands, such as a semicolon, but after a bit of DuckDuckGoing I couldn't find any such separator.

This is for a realm, and I'm running the Java version.

### Example

For example, I'd like to be able to do things like compose a little script like this in an external editor:

```
/setblock 0 0 0 air
/playsound block.bell.use master @p
```

Then copy it to clipboard, open Minecraft and press "t" to open the command line / chat. Then if I paste, unfortunately what I get is

```
/setblock 0 0 0 air/playsound block.bell.use master @p
```

What I'd like to happen is for it to run several commands.

**Update** I don't mean functions, as I want anyone to be able to paste in commands, not only realm admins but anyone with cheats on.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can just execute the commands one after the other.

Comment: @FabianRöling For example if I created a tool that turns a 16x16 pixelart into setblock commands, that might be 256 commands, which would be too many to paste in separately. If I require downloading and reuploading the realm, then non-admins would not be able to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before functions and structure blocks existed, the best way to send someone a command block contraption was a "one-command-creation", which summoned a falling command block riding a falling command block riding a falling command block …

Currently there is a bug that breaks these: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-145113
But you can work around it by using other entities in between that instantly die. So you can for example do it like this:

`summon falling_block ~ ~2 ~ {Time:1,BlockState:{Name:"command_block"},TileEntityData:{auto:1,Command:"say 1"},Passengers:[{id:"armor_stand",Health:0,Passengers:[{id:"falling_block",Time:1,BlockState:{Name:"command_block"},TileEntityData:{auto:1,Command:"say 2"},Passengers:[{id:"armor_stand",Health:0,Passengers:[{id:"falling_block",Time:1,BlockState:{Name:"command_block"},TileEntityData:{auto:1,Command:"say 3"}}]}]}]}]}`

This executes all three commands, `say 1`, `say 2` and `say 3`, in that order. If you also want to clean up afterwards, you can simply add another command block that removes the tower:

`summon falling_block ~ ~2 ~ {Time:1,BlockState:{Name:"command_block"},TileEntityData:{auto:1,Command:"say 1"},Passengers:[{id:"armor_stand",Health:0,Passengers:[{id:"falling_block",Time:1,BlockState:{Name:"command_block"},TileEntityData:{auto:1,Command:"say 2"},Passengers:[{id:"armor_stand",Health:0,Passengers:[{id:"falling_block",Time:1,BlockState:{Name:"command_block"},TileEntityData:{auto:1,Command:"say 3"},Passengers:[{id:"armor_stand",Health:0,Passengers:[{id:"falling_block",Time:1,BlockState:{Name:"command_block"},TileEntityData:{auto:1,Command:"fill ~ ~-3 ~ ~ ~ ~ air"}}]}]}]}]}]}]}`

---

[Michael Dibbets/Tschallacka](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/134125/tschallacka) has created a generator in 2020 for these combined commands: https://www.tschallacka.de/minecraft/multiple-commands-generator ([mirror](https://jsfiddle.net/Tschallacka/evwb39dr/embedded/result), [archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20200218143641/https://jsfiddle.net/Tschallacka/evwb39dr/embedded/result))

Enter your commands in the text field above the red button, one per line, without slashes in front (so like a function) and press the button. The bottom text field will then contain the combined command.
The generator does not validate if the commands are valid and it does not ignore empty lines or lines starting with `#`, so you cannot simply copy-paste function files into it.

Licensing information on [his profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/134125/tschallacka) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20200218143639/https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/134125/tschallacka)).

Comment: I suspected some hack like this must be possible. Thank you!

Comment: felt inspired by your answer, don't know if there is already one out there https://jsfiddle.net/Tschallacka/evwb39dr/embedded/result

Comment: @Tschallacka Awesome! But I already found a bug: The `/fill` command always goes three blocks down, no matter how many commands I enter. It should be as many blocks down as I entered commands.

Comment: But that could potentially go through bedrock then? How about replacing with lava to eat the tower when the entities drop in?

Comment: Why would you care about bedrock if the player has command access?And no,it shouldn't remove any other blocks than the tower if nothing went wrong before.You have a command block with the first command,on top of that a command block with the second command,on top of that a command block removing from2down to the current position,meaning the two command blocks with the first and second command and itself.It just removes what was added.The only way this could remove anything else is if you had a ceiling above where you put the original command block,but then the entire setup doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @FabianRöling updated it, better like this? And I cared because I was thinking of adventure maps etc... where players might slip somehow down. but the command blocks would be sealed off then anyways

Comment: Awesome! Now of course I can come up with many potential optional features, like ignoring empty lines or lines starting with `#`. That way you could just copy-paste function files into it. Or checking if the commands are valid, but that's of course a gigantic project (and might lead to licensing issues if you just drop Brigadier into it).

Comment: Would this work for more than a few commands? It seems like the command would reach the chat character limit quite quickly.

Comment: @AMJ Those things are usually executed in command blocks anyway, exactly because of that. It also has the advantage of almost guaranteeing a solid surface for the blocks to land on. Not even a single command can be executed from chat with this system. Also, it seems to be broken in the latest snapshot, even with my workaround. Always nice when the workaround for a bug gets broken by yet another bug… -.-

Comment: [The second bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-173220) was fixed, the workaround works again.

Comment: I just heard that apparently in the time of 1.8/1.9, it was possible to give the riding `falling_sand` upwards motion to avoid them getting stuck inside each other and dropping. But I don't know why that worked, it doesn't anymore anyway, because it immediately gets the `Motion` of the "vehicle" (lower falling block).

Comment: @Tschallacka Your command generator is now only in the bottom right part of the website and there's a lot of other stuff that is probably not meant to be there.

Comment: @FabianRöling jsfiddle doesn't seem to want to do full screen anymore. I've ported it to my website. Do note my website sometimes is slow as molasses as it's on shared hosting and sometimes the server gets shut off due to inactivity because nobody visits ;-) Just be patient for it to load. https://www.tschallacka.de/minecraft/multiple-commands-generator

Answer (score 8):

You could do this by writing a [function](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Function_(Java_Edition)) (*.mcfunction* file) and placing it in a datapack in the map folder. To create a function, follow these steps:

1. Open notepad (or your text editor of choice), and enter the commands you wish to run, each on their own line.
2. Save the file, name it whatever you want, (replace *.txt* with *.mcfunction*) on your desktop.
3. Create folders in this order:

   `datapacks / [name of datapack] / data / [namespace] / functions`
4. Move the *.mcfunction* file you created into the functions folder, and move the datapacks folder into your world folder. (for a Realm, you will first need to download the map - go to World backups and Download latest)
5. (for a Realm) Upload the modified map to the Realm.
6. Run the function with `/function [namespace] : [function name]`. This can be done by a player or from a command block.

*Note: @p selector will be relative to the command block or player that ran the function, in this usecase I'm assuming @a would fit better.*

Comment: Thanks, so sounds like pasting multiple isn't possible. I wanted anyone on a realm to be able to paste the commands, not just admins, and would have been more user-friendly to not require downloading and uploading.

Comment: As an admin/just a guy who runs his own server, this is perfect! Now I can script up all my command files and just run them from my world

Comment: Note: plugin commands cannot be executed using datapack functions, only vanilla commands. Also - in order for function to be available, datapack must contain `pack.mcmeta` file and must be then enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the pixel art already created  then clone it to the position then play the bell sound to the player,  this is best done with  tags so everything goes to the right player .

One thing you could also do is to have a structure block with the commands already inside, then have setblock command that places preset structureblock

Answer (score 0):

One can copy multiple commands into the clipboard then paste into a Minecraft server window. I show how in YouTube post at

Alternatively, one can use AutoHotKey to load a text file into a Minecraft client (game window). Also available on my channel.

Comment: Links and videos are helpful in a post, but *make sure the post is still clear without them*. You should explain in your post directly what this will do, and go into more detail on how to do it.