# Setblock Command not working with specific parameters in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a game for myself and my friends to play, and I have a prototype working in my test world that works perfectly, however, the game relies on the fact that we will be playing on a random seed, and because of that I am converting all of the command blocks into one long command that can be run to set up the game on a new world very quickly. In doing this I have found one command that does not seem to work, I have tested it all I can but cannot find what syntax I have wrong.

The command ("`/kill @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:compass"}}]`") works perfectly when I type it into another command block or chat.

Here is the command:

```
/setblock ~6 ~-1 ~1 repeating_command_block[conditional=false,facing=up]{Command:"/kill @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:compass"}}]",auto:1b} replace
```

According to the game, there should be another "`}`" right after the "`{id`", I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an 'unexpected token' error with this command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246064/why-am-i-getting-an-unexpected-token-error-with-this-command)

Answer (score 0):

That error message is indeed very confusing. Your real problem is that you have quotes inside quotes. So the game sees `/kill @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:` as a string, then `minecraft:compass` as outside the string (which is were it should actually show an error) and then `}}]` as another string.

The fix: "Escaping". Quotation marks inside strings have to be replaced with `\"` (and backslashes inside strings with `\\`, not relevant here). So your fixed command is:

```
/setblock ~6 ~-1 ~1 repeating_command_block[facing=up]{Command:"kill @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:\"minecraft:compass\"}}]",auto:1b} replace
```

I also removed the `/` inside the command block, since that is not needed, and the block state `conditional=false`, since that is the default anyway.

---

If you want a convenient one-command creator that works in the latest versions, including a bug workaround, I can recommend the one linked here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/364048/171580