# How to run a redstone signal if a scoreboard is a certain amount

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

Here's what I'm trying to do, I have a scoreboard that's called `Deaths`, I want to run a command if it gets to 5, how can I do this?

Comment: First off, you don't want to use redstone to do this.  [Redstone and commands don't mix](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/235449/1351).

Comment: MBraedleys comment is incorrect (this is bedrock)

Answer (score 1):

Have a repeating command block running the below command into a conditional chain block which starts your logic when deaths reaches 5.

```
/scoreboard players test @a Deaths 5
```

If you need to create a redstone signal you can /setblock  x y z redstone_block from the next command block in the chain.

Comment: Or just run out a comparator instead, much better option if you need it right there