# Is there a command to detect if tnt explodes?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to make a tnt that create 2 new primed tnt every time one of them explode. Is there a command to do that?

Comment: Keep in mind to be careful with this because normal methods would make it multiple infinitely until the game crashes

Comment: I’m trying to test if my device can handle it

Comment: no device can handle infinitely expanding entities as it expands infinitely and will crash no mtter what device it is. You would have to have a special method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for any primed TNT in your world, and if it succeeds, set a redstone block to a nearby location which is next to another command block:

```
Rpt: /testfor @e[type=tnt]
Cnd: /setblock 12 23 34 redstone_block
```

Comment: What do rpt and cnd mean?

Comment: @Penguin Command block settings. If you were to make a command chain out of these, those display the required settings for the command blocks. CND = conditional, RPT = repeating.

Comment: I mean a command to check if the primed tnt explodes.

Comment: Probably I can add delay to the command block

Comment: @Redstoner1635 Yes. When the `/testfor` detects a primed TNT, wait 4 seconds and then run the command.

Comment: You may wanna hold on here: This answer by itself will not work because if you use the summon TNT command it will grow infinitely and crash the game. On normal uses this would work, but not for this.

Comment: @Penguin Fair point. I changed the answer to setting a redstone block to a nearby location, which runs another command. While the command setting the redstone block only runs once, the commands activated by the redstone block are only run once.

Comment: @Penguin But the part where I'm stuck is how to get rid of the redstone block once the primed TNT is no longer present. I need some way to run a setblock with air when there's *no* primed TNT. How do I do that?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 hook up a `testfor` to a redstone torch not-gate and then have that start power a command block that sets it to air.

Comment: @Penguin ...which ties back into [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/377672/250180). Mixing commands and redstone is a *last resort*. I will only do so if there's no other way to solve.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 remember we had this discussion like a month ago? There is no (known) way in Minecraft's current state. Also if you set it up right there is no disadvantages in it. You just have to know how to start it, as sometimes starting it can be a little weird. Once its set up theres no reason not to

Comment: @Penguin Yes, I do remember said discussion, and I haven't given up on pursuing a workaround for at least some, if not all commands!

Comment: I’ll accept your answer.